# Getting Xdebug work in an environment with IDE on Windows and code base on Linux connected via NFS

Tags: php, xdebug, nfs, zend-studio, portforwarding

I want to debug with Xdebug in a development environment, that is a little complex.

**The issue I'm observing:**

When I start debugging from my eclipse / Zend Studio, the launching stops on `57%`:

> Launching myproject
>
> Launching: waiting for Xdebug session

**Environment**

I work on a **Windows 7 Ultimate** machine. The IDE is **Zend Studio**. The machine connects as **NFS** client to a **Linux Mint** computer with the code on it. The code is executed in a **Vagrant**/**LXC** **VM**.

In order that works, I set up **port forwarding** (**PuTTY**: `[Session Settings] -> Connection -> Tunnels` and there `Source Port` & `Destination` -> `Add`):

```
L80:myproject.local:80
L3306:myproject.local:3306
L15672:myproject.local:15672
L8983:myproject.local:8983
R10.0.3.1:9000:localhost:9000
L81:anotherproject.local:80
```

The *Xdebug settings on the Server (VM)* are pretty common:

```
zend_extension=/usr/lib/php5/20121212/xdebug.so

xdebug.profiler_enable=Off
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger=On
xdebug.max_nesting_level=1000

xdebug.remote_enable=On
# sr computer
#xdebug.remote_host="10.0.3.1"
# ax laptop
xdebug.remote_host="10.98.117.1"
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.remote_handler="dbgp"
xdebug.remote_autostart=On
```

The *PHP Server settings in Zend Studio* (`[Preferences] -> PHP -> PHP Servers`) don't contain any special stuff as well.

The *Xdebug configuration in Zend Studio* is set to the default configurations.

The *Xdebug session in Zend Studio* is just common as well. I also tried to configure a tunnel connection, but the connection could not be built, at least with my credentials (I used my username and password for the Linux machine).

What is wrong here? How to get it work?

Comment: You need to change your configuration in Zend Studio.

Comment: Thank you for you comment. Do you have a guess, which configuration that is?

Comment: Not out of my head I used a tutorial on the internet. Just search google you'll find enough about this subject.

Comment: So, your comments don't say much more than, that I need to configure something, in order it works. Thanks! ;) Please feel free to write a new comment or an answer, if you have more exact info.